# change the columns width of entire excel sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to change all columns width of multiple sheets in my excel file. What I found in other posts was about changing the width of one column.
How can I do this?

This is what I tried but failed:

```
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('my_file.xlsx')
    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
        for column in sheet.columns:
            sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the following code this one build for dynamic cell resize but can use for your purpose also

```
column_widths = []
for row in data:
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        if len(column_widths) > i:
            if len(cell) > column_widths[i]:
                column_widths[i] = 50
        else:
            column_widths += [50]

for i, column_width in enumerate(column_widths):
    worksheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i+1)].width = column_width
```

Comment: I saw that before. I don't know how to use it. for instance last line what is `get_column_letter()` ?

Comment: HI that is an in build method that have to import from the library itself `from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. That was `from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter` by the way

Comment: Ahhh new one it might changed thank you for sharing.